# Which web application technology should I use for graphs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, graph, neo4j

I'd like to create a webapplication that allows users to work with graphs. (Retrieve data related to nodes, create new ones, drag them, etc.) I thought it would be a good idea to store the data in a graph database (e.g. neo4j) and display it with some JS-Frameworks (e.g. http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/).

Currently I'm not sure which web application technology I should use. Since one requirement is to use microsoft technologies wherever possible I thought it might be a good idea to go with ASP.NET in C#. However, during the first chapter of my ASP.NET book the following is mentioned:

> it’s worth noting that ASP.NET is not the best platform for writing
>   complex, app-like client-side programs

So, which technology should I use to create my web application? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
from my experience, I think one of the JVM based languages like Java is a save bet, if not the most sexy one. And it works best with Neo4j, and Java 8  is really nice syntax-wise.

For JS-based frameworks, try Node.js and the Neo4j REST API, should work good, too.

Comment: Because of your proposal I tried Node.js with Express and Jade yesterday. Works fine! Would you consider this choice as a good one?